# Mongos alway exit unexpectedly

Tags: mongodb

I started one Mongos server by the following command:

```
nohup mongos --port 57017 --configdb configsvr1:47017,configsvr2:47017,configsvr3:47017 > s.nohup 2>&1 &
```

configsvr* are configuration servers. my problem is that Mongos instance always exit after a few hour.
The Mongos log I found as following:

```
W SHARDING [LockPinger] Error encountered while stopping ping on mongos_server:
57017:1472436263:-1365656364 :: caused by :: 17382 
Can't use connection pool during shutdown
I SHARDING [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc:0
```